# target.closest in Safari on iOS not working

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events

So I have this simple javascript code, that should enable users to collapse/expand content by clicking either on a little plus sign in the accordion header, or by clicking the accordion header in general.

It works fine on IE, Edge, Chrome (on all platforms) but not in Safari on iOS (Version 11+).
In Safari it only works with the click on the plus-sign - not on the accordion header in general.

I must be missing something obvious, but I can't find out what.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (
          event.target.classList.contains("accordion__expand") ||
          event.target.closest(".accordion__header") != null 
        ) {
            event.target.closest(".accordion").classList.toggle("js-active");
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) doesn't work in IE but works in Safari. Are you sure?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman - yes I have a polyfill for closest on IE.

Comment: Ah, there you go. So what's the error in Safari then?

Comment: `*The Safari browser for iOS is tied to the operating system, so the numbers used are based on the OS version.` [Can I use... Support tables for HTML5, CSS3, etc](https://caniuse.com/#feat=element-closest)

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman yes, sure I am aware. I just edited the question to clarify that the issue is on newer versions of iOS. This really has me puzzled...